# i18next Module in ExpressJS and Client Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, express, i18next

I'm using [i18next](http://i18next.com/) module in my NodeJs/ExpressJS web application.

The translation files are in `/locales` folder.

From i18next.com, it can be used in client side

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[PATH]/i18next.js" />
...
<span href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></span>
```

I installed the module via `npm install i18next`.

In `app.js`, I set static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

How to refer to the path of `i18next.js` file in client side? The path for the translation files?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="???" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the locales folder is within the public directory, then it can be referred as 
src="/locales/i18next.js"